# Check first character of a pointer to an array

Tags: c, string

I have an array of pointers to characters:

```
char *myStrings[40];
```

Eventually, `myStrings[0]` will equal "example" or something of the sort. 
I'd like to check the first character and see if it's equal to `e`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `if((*myStrings)[0] == 'e')`

Comment: You have an array of pointers to char (`char *[]`), not a pointer to an array of char (`char (*)[]`).

Comment: You know that `myStrings[0]` is a "string". Now do you know how to access an arbitrary characters of a string? What if you have `char *mySingleString;`, how would you then access the first character of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer is a variable that holds the address to something else as its value. To access the value at the address held by the pointer (e.g. the *something else*), you *dereference* the pointer with the unary `'*'`.

Since you have an *array of pointers*, you will need to dereference the first element of the array, e.g. `mystrings[0]`. With **C - operator precedence**, the `[..]` has greater precedence than `'*'`, so you can simply look at the first character of the string pointed to by `mystrings[0]` by dereferencing the pointer, e.g. `*mystrings[0]`

A short example will help:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 40

int main (void) {

    char *string = "example",       /* string literal */
        *arrptrs[MAX] = { NULL };   /* array of pointers */

    arrptrs[0] = string;    /* set 1st pointer to point to string */

    if (*arrptrs[0] == 'e')         /* test 1st char is 'e' */
        printf ("found : %s\n", arrptrs[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Since you are looking at the first element of your array of pointers, you can also print the string `"example"` by dereferecing the array, e.g.

```
        printf ("found : %s\n", *arrptrs);
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arrptrs
found : example
```

(the output is the same regardless whether you access the first element with `arrptrs[0]` or `*arrptrs`, they are equivalent -- do you understand why?)

**note:** always pay attention to C-Operator Precedence. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 2):

Each element of this array is a string, then consider that we have:

```
char *myStrings[40] = {"Example", " 01", " - ", "Hello", ",World!\n"};
```

so

```
myStrings[0] is equals to "Example" 
myStrings[1] is equals to " 01"
...
```

Now, we have to access the first element of `*myStrings[0]` by this way

`*(myStrings)[0]` or `*myStrings[0]`

```
if (*(myStrings)[0] == 'E'){
    do something
}
```

or

```
if (*myStrings[0] == 'E'){
    do something
}
```

Comment: `*myStrings[0] = "Example"` - typo, shouldn't have `*`?